# magento 2 custom Theme preview image not showing in admin

Tags: magento2

I created theme.xml with content below: (at: `app/code/design/frontend/Vendor/theme_directory/theme.xml`)

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
   <title>mytheme</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
   <parent>Magento/luma</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
  <media>
      <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
   </media>
</theme>
```

and despite I have "preview.jpg" at `app/code/design/frontend/vendor/theme_directory/media/preview.jpg`, it is not showing in admin.

Comment: Can you add some more information? Did you follow the instructions available online for creating a theme?

Answer (score 0):

Your Path is already Wrong. So, it's Not Getting on them.
Please check below path:

> app/design/frontend/media/preview.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Theme Preview image loads from app/design/vendor/theme_directory/theme.xml file

```
<media>
          <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> 
</media>
```

put image on

```
 app/design/frontend/vendor/theme_directory/media/preview.png
```

If this media tag and path to the image is not specified theme preview image will not be loaded. You can follow this link to learn about Magento 2 Themes and Theme creation
You can check-in here: [Magent2 Theme Overview](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix that issues by deleting "design/theme/theme_id" from `core_config_data` table, and by deleting theme record from `theme` table as well. After that, I just activated theme again and thus, there is an image preview.